# trying to write a function that returns every third element in a list in racket language

Tags: racket

Trying to write a function that returns every third element in a list
   including the first element in racket.  All I get now is my code blowing up               with a first: contract violation
   expected: (and/c list? (not/c empty?))
   given: 4

```
(define l (list 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9))

(define (skipper lst)
   (if (null? lst)
       '() 
       (cons (first lst) 
             (skipper (car (cdr (cdr (cdr lst))))))))
(skipper l)
```

Comment: sorry skipper in the code is supposed to be the recursive function call name, I change my function name at the top of the function when I posted the code and prematurely hit post questions before thinking about the body of the code.  My apologize. In my actual code, the function name and the recursive name in  the body of the function are the same.  that is not the issue for the error.

Comment: `triple` is supposed to take a list, right? Is it a function from `[Listof X] -> [Listof X]` ?

Comment: Assuming that's true, in the body of `triple`, `lst` has type `[Listof X]`, and so does `(cdr lst)`, `(cdr (cdr lst))`, and `(cdr (cdr (cdr lst)))`, because if you give `cdr` a list it produces another list for the rest. But, you have a `car` in there too and I don't know why. Because if you give `car` a flat list you won't get a list back. `(car (cdr (cdr (cdr lst))))` will _not_ be a `[Listof X]`.

Comment: @teaNcode You can (and should!) edit your question if you’ve posted it with some mistakes.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was just the `car` around `cdddr`.

```
(define l (list 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9))

(define (skipper lst)
   (if (null? lst)
       '() 
       (cons (first lst) 
             (skipper (if (< (length lst) 3)
                          '()
                          (cdddr lst))))))

(skipper l) ;; '(1 4 7)
```

**Generalized Solution**

```
(define (my-cdr lst)      ;; `cdr` behaving like in common-lisp: (cdr '()) -> '()
  (cond ((null? lst) '())
        (else (cdr lst))))

(define (multi-cdr lst k) ;; apply `my-cdr` k-times on `lst`
  (cond ((zero? k) lst)
        (else (multi-cdr (my-cdr lst) (- k 1)))))

(define (skipper lst k)
   (if (null? lst)
       '() 
       (cons (first lst) 
             (skipper (multi-cdr lst k) k))))
```

Test it:

```
(skipper l 3) ;; '(1 4 7)
(skipper l 4) ;; '(1 5 9)
(skipper l 2) ;; '(1 3 5 7 9)
(skipper l 1) ;; '(1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9)
```

Comment: @PetSerAl thanks! Comming from common-lisp I forgot that in Racket `(cdr '())` doesn't work. Modified so that it works.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that you cannot call `(cdr (cdr (cdr lst)))` when `lst` has less than 3 elements.

You tagged this with racket, so I'm going to show you a solution using [`match`](https://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/match.html)

```scm
(define (skipper l)
  (match l

    ;; some element and at least 3 more
    ((list a rest ..3)
     (cons a (skipper (cddr rest))))

    ;; at least one element
    ((cons a _)
     (list a))

    ;; otherwise
    (else
     empty)))

(skipper '())
;; '()

(skipper '(0))
;; '(0)

(skipper '(0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7))
;; '(0 3 6)

(skipper '(0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9))
;; '(0 3 6 9)
```

This solution doesn't use `length` which unnecessarily computes the length of the list